# Convert image and audio files to binary in Java

Tags: image, image-processing, binary

I want to convert an image and an audio file into a binary stream, process it and then reconstruct the image from the same binary stream in Java. How can I do that? Has anybody worked on this? Please help me out as soon as possible. Any hints or pseudocode will be highly appreciated.
This is how I tried to do it but it just creates an empty file while reconstructing the image.
For image to binary:-

```
        File file = new File("E:\\image.jpg");
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);

        // write image to byte array in-memory (jpg format)
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", b);

        byte[] jpgByteArray = b.toByteArray();

        // convert it to a String with 0s and 1s
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte by : jpgByteArray) {
            sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(by & 0xFF));
```

For binary to image:-

```
        byte[] original = obj.orig_seq.getBytes();

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(original);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);

        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg",
                 new File("E:\\mypic_new.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 3):

To use Binary String you can use this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("YourImage.jpg"))) {
    for (int i; (i = is.read()) != -1;) {
         String temp = "0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(i).toUpperCase();
        if (temp.length() == 1) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        temp = temp.substring(temp.length() - 8); 
        sb.append(temp).append(' ');
    }
}
System.out.print(sb);
```

and here is your desired output

`0000000 11111111 00000111 00011111 00101111 01111111`

you can also use Hexadecimal and convert your file into a simple string like this (suggestion)

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("YourFile.txt"))) {
    for (int i; (i = is.read()) != -1;) {
        String temp = Integer.toHexString(i).toUpperCase();
        if (temp.length() == 1) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        sb.append(temp).append(' ');
    }
}
System.out.print(sb);
```

and the output would be something like this

```
00 FF 07 1F 2F 7F
```